# Save State of a Direct3D Device

Tags: c++, direct3d

State should include at least the following:

- All settings set via
  SetStreamResource()
- Indices

I have a class whose Draw() function will call SetStreamResource, set Indices and eventually call DrawIndexedPrimitive(). I would like to restore the device state before Draw() returns.

I am looking for something along the lines of GDI's SaveDC()/RestoreDC().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

State blocks are the mechanism provided by the API to save and restore chunks of device state.  I cover the details of state blocks in Chapter 3. Direct3D Devices from my book [The Direct3D Graphics Pipeline](http://www.xmission.com/~legalize/book/download/).  You can download the PDF for that chapter from the link above.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like these will do it:

```
Microsoft::DirectX::Direct3D::Device::BeginStateBlock
Microsoft::DirectX::Direct3D::Device::EndStateBlock
```